# Save passphrase for gpg or gpg2

Tags: node.js, bash, gnupg

There are answers I've found on Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu and Stack Exchange but none works for me.

I need to set up crontab in a Linux box with these:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.16
$ gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.22
$ gpg-agent --version
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.0.22
```

I'm execute the bash command from Node.js

```
exec(`gpg --passphrase-file <path>passphrase.txt -d ${encryptedFile} > ${decryptedFile}`)
```

I need to set up the `gpg/gpg2` command so it won't prompt for passphrase. I've tried these inside my `exec()`:

```
gpg2 --batch --yes --no-tty
gpg --batch --yes
gpg2 --passphrase <passphrase>
with and without -d
const passphrase = fs.readFileSync(<passphrase-file>, (err, data)=>{})
`gpg --passphrase ${passphrase}...`
```

None of them works, even though:

```
$ gpg --import pubkey.txt 
gpg: key ######: "Name <name@email>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
$ gpg --import privkey.txt 
gpg: key ######: already in secret keyring
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
gpg:  secret keys unchanged: 1
```

I've also added keys for `gpg2`.

Comment: Please note that triple-backticks do not work here. Please use indentation instead - there is a button to do this in the editor.